# Transform Property CSS3 scale but stick at bottom

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, scale

Did anyone know how to scale an image but stick with bottom?
Below is my code, my images scale at middle, but I need them to stick at bottom.

```
.animation_scale{
position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:55px;
display:block;
z-index:-10;
bottom : 0;}

.animation_scale img{
animation-name:animation_scale;
animation-duration:1s;
animation-timing-function:ease;
animation-delay:0s;
animation-iteration-count:1;
animation-direction:alternate;
animation-play-state:running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    /* Firefox: */
-moz-animation-name:animation_scale;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
-moz-animation-delay:0s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
-moz-animation-direction:alternate;
-moz-animation-play-state:running;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name:animation_scale;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

@keyframes animation_scale {
0%   {
-webkit-transform:  scale(0.2) translate(0px);
-moz-transform:  scale(0.2) translate(0px);
-o-transform:  scale(0.2) translate(0px);}

100% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.0) skew(0deg) translateY(-10px);
-moz-transform: scale(1.0) skew(0deg) translateY(-10px);
-o-transform: scale(1.0) skew(0deg) translateY(-10px);}}

@-moz-keyframes animation_scale /* Firefox */
{0%   {
-moz-transform:  scale(0.2) translate(0px);}

100% {
-moz-transform:  scale(1.0) translateY(-10px);}}

@-webkit-keyframes animation_scale{ /* Safari and Chrome */

0%   {
-webkit-transform:  scale(0.2) translate(0px);}

100% {
-webkit-transform:  scale(1.0) translateY(-10px);}}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `transform-origin` `center bottom`

Here is working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7CytE/)

Answer (score 6):

Use `transform-origin` property on elements on which a `transform` is applied.

It defines the "center" point of the transformation :

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
transform-origin: 50% 100%;
```

or

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
-moz-transform-origin: center bottom;
-o-transform-origin: center bottom;
transform-origin: center bottom;
```

See more : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Thanks you, transform-origin is put on @keyframes?

Comment: Either in keyframes or in .animation_scale img{...}. I'd vote for second option.